# SNMP - get complete Mac table in one call

Tags: snmp, mac-address

For my project I need to download mac table from switch and do it as fast as possible. Official [solution](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801576ff.shtml) is kind of slow. It requires to get list of all Vlan's, and for each one trigger separate call of snmpwalk with `OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1` and community string indexed with vlan number. It can take significant amount of time, since number of vlan's on our switches ranges in tens.
Is there a way to get all mac addresses from mac table at once(some special community index representing all available vlan indexes)?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7):

I think `BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbTable` (1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3) will do the job. One can simply retrieve `dot1dTpFdbPort` (1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2) to retrieve *learned* MAC -> PORT table.  For my DLINK DGS-1216T I can get mac-to-port table from my Linux box by this command:

```
$ snmpwalk -O0sUX -v2c -Cc -c public 192.168.0.1 BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort
```

Additionally I found extra (17th) port number for maintenance MAC.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Cisco switches. That will not return the MACs in extended VLANs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to retreive the `ipNetToMediaTable` ({iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) ip(4) ipNetToMediaTable(22)} or 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22) from your switch management address. It represents the IP Address Translation table used for mapping from IP addresses to physical addresses.

----EDIT----

If you want to [Use SNMP to Find a Port Number from a MAC Address on a Catalyst Switch](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801c9199.shtml) with a minimum of frames you can us a Get-Bulk PDU, it assume that you switch is SNMP V2c.

Comment: But I need MAC table, not ARP table.